# Why this line giving syntax error near '|'

Tags: linux

I am facing a syntax error while running below the line. The syntax error is coming near '|'.

```
for i in git status --porcelain --untracked-files=no | cut -d' ' -f 3;
```

I tried to run with removing space between f and 3 but still getting the same error :

```
for i in git status --porcelain --untracked-files=no | cut -d' ' -f3;
```

Comment: There are multiple issues. You'd need to enter `git status` (using back-ticks, which unfortunately formats my comment so they don't show here), and there's both a "do" and a "done" keyword missing.

Answer (score 0):

```
git status --porcelain --untracked-files=no | while read line 
do
  cut -d' ' -f 3 <<< $line
done
```

Using for i in... you will be reading data in one space delimiter field as a time. With git status, it would be better to read line by line. As we are looping, we will need a do and a done. With each line read into the variable line, we redirect the line back into the cut command to get the second space delimited field.

Instead of looping through the output, you can pipe the complete output line by line into cut and so:

```
git status --porcelain --untracked-files=no | cut -d " " -f 3
```

Another way of doing this is through awk:

```
git status --porcelain --untracked-files=no | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

Take the output from git status and then print just the second space delimited field.